# How do I echo a php variable inside html tags inside an if statement?

Tags: php, html, variables, if-statement, echo

Im having trouble trying to get this to work.

```
 <?php

   $_SESSION['age'] = 11

        if($_SESSION['age'] < 14) {
            echo "<h2>Your only $_SESSION['age']? Thats Young!</h2>";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to echo PHP variable inside `echo` function, you must as first break echo with `"`, then add a "merge char" `.`, then your variable and then again "merge char" and `"`.

Also don't forget to add semicolon to end of your line which contains definition of `$_SESSION['age']`.

Edit your code to:

```
 <?php

   $_SESSION['age'] = 11;

        if($_SESSION['age'] < 14) {
            echo "<h2>Your only ".$_SESSION['age']."? Thats Young!</h2>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: $_SESSION['age'] = 11 syntax error

Comment: add `;` to end of your line with `$_SESSION['age'] = 11` (edited in my code)

Comment: good, also mention one more point, make sure you are using session_start(); otherwise it will not work.

Comment: if you are using session variables, shouldn't you be GETTING the  $_SESSION['age'] variable instead of SETTING it? (for example $age =  $_SESSION['age']); Otherwise there is no benefit in referencing the $_session variables.

Comment: Thanks Heaps, This Worked! I'm pretty new to php so I'm just mucking around with it at the moment to see what I can learn. :)

Comment: Also, this wasn't my full code. I'm making a quick game using html forms and php. The age is defined elsewhere on a different page :P. I just added the "$_SESSION['age' = 11;" for reference.

Comment: if resolved, please accept this answer. @BaileyWarrick

Comment: Yeah, I have. It said i needed to wait a few minutes.